# Need CSS (PHP won't work) to swap header images, based on device type, in Wordpress TwentySeventeen

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, header

I need the CSS to swap header images in the TwentySeventeen Theme, based on the "current" width of the browser window.

Note: PHP will NOT work, since it runs ONLY at load time. If the user changes the orientation of the device, after load, the PHP won't detect that change, since the PHP has already completed. The solution MUST be CSS, since it is LIVE and will detect changes after the page has loaded.

The affected site is: http://RVInspector.pro/

One of the swap images is at: http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-mheader-2.jpg

FYI, I am able to make my own sites, developed from scratch, do just about anything. But I'm at a loss for how to make these otherwise simple images swap, when dealing with Wordpress.

I tried two different PHP fixes, before I realized that PHP won't detect changes after page load. I'm including one of the options that I tried.

This option appeared to have no effect.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 425px ){ 
  .page-id-155 .ewf-header-image-option{
      background-image: url("http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-mheader-2.jpg");
      max-height: 150px;
      background-position: 49% 0px;
  }
}
```

My header image is the recommended size and works well on a laptop or desktop. But it contains graphic text that overflows the left and right edges of the screen, when viewed on a phone or pad. I have created several alternate images that will suffice. But I can't make them swap in, when the device is mobile.

Comment: Just change the `background-image` `url` based on the `width` in the media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CSS based solution that overlays the header image with the resized variant

```
.wp-custom-header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-bottom: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    }

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .wp-custom-header::before {
            background-image: url(http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-mheader-2.jpg);
    }
}
```

It is somewhat inelegant as it loads images without displaying them, so here is an HTML based solution for template-parts > header > header-img.php

```
<!--Replaces: <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?> -->
<div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header">
    <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-head-1024x614.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-head-768x460.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 300px)" srcset="http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-mheader-2.jpg">
        <img src="http://rvinspector.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/rv-inspector-motorhome-head.jpg" alt="RV Inspector Pro - Certified RV &amp; Motorhome Inspections" sizes="100vw">
    </picture>
</div>
```

Note that both these options overwrite the header set in WP itself, so you will have to update the URLs manually if you want to change the header image.

Comment: Thanks, Swimmer F. That CSS was the key. I ended up modifying it a little. I added a second alternative image and converted it to ems, instead of px. I couldn't use the PHP. But your CSS was the key that made it possible. Thanks again.